# MudBlazor - ASP.NET Core hosted

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I have created .NET 7 Blazor-hosted application with Identity Server 4 and role-based authentication - the latest version.

There is page fetchdata as we know - it comes out of the box.

I have tried to remove bootstrap, CSS files etc, as per other topics of StackOverflow, thng is, this is the latest version of .NET and with previous versions, I did not have these issues, the process was the same.

I have added the latest version of MudBlazor:

- problem does not exist once I access fetchdata component via menu
- this problem appears once I try to access fetchdata directly from the URL

> crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find 'mudElementRef.getBoundingClientRect' ('mudElementRef' was undefined).
> Error: Could not find 'mudElementRef.getBoundingClientRect' ('mudElementRef' was undefined).
> at https://localhost:7060/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:328
> at Array.forEach ()
> at a.findFunction (https://localhost:7060/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:296)
> at _ (https://localhost:7060/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:2442)
> at https://localhost:7060/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:3330
> at new Promise ()
> at Object.beginInvokeJSFromDotNet (https://localhost:7060/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:3311)
> at Object.Gt [as invokeJSFromDotNet] (https://localhost:7060/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:62537)
> at Object.Ii (https://localhost:7060/_framework/dotnet.7.0.0.amub20uvka.js:5:71465)
> at _mono_wasm_invoke_js_blazor (https://localhost:7060/_framework/dotnet.7.0.0.amub20uvka.js:14:103886)
> Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find 'mudElementRef.getBoundingClientRect' ('mudElementRef' was undefined).
> Error: Could not find 'mudElementRef.getBoundingClientRect' ('mudElementRef' was undefined).
> at https://localhost:7060/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:328
> at Array.forEach ()
> at a.findFunction (https://localhost:7060/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:296)
> at _ (https://localhost:7060/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:2442)
> at https://localhost:7060/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:3330
> at new Promise ()
> at Object.beginInvokeJSFromDotNet (https://localhost:7060/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:3311)
> at Object.Gt [as invokeJSFromDotNet] (https://localhost:7060/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:62537)
> at Object.Ii (https://localhost:7060/_framework/dotnet.7.0.0.amub20uvka.js:5:71465)
> at _mono_wasm_invoke_js_blazor (https://localhost:7060/_framework/dotnet.7.0.0.amub20uvka.js:14:103886)
> at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.d__16`1[[MudBlazor.Interop.BoundingClientRect, MudBlazor, Version=6.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext()
> at MudBlazor.MudDrawer.UpdateHeight()
> at MudBlazor.MudDrawer.OnAfterRenderAsync(Boolean firstRender)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState) <

Comment: How do you remove Bootstrap from Blazor?

Answer (score 0):

All that you have to do is to add AddMudServices() under the builder in the Program.cs pipeline - under the builder on the top.

```
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddMudServices();
```

as well you don't need to delete bootstrap and custom CSS style files.